# how to change the alignment of check boxes in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, html

I am facing an issue to change the alignment of check box in my html.

this is my HTML:

```
<ol id="menutree">
  <li>

    <label class="menu_label" for="c1">Menu Gen14 Am0a1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c1" />                             <!-- input must follow label for safari -->
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="c2" class="menu_label">Menu Am1a1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" />
        <ol>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Ap1a1</a></li>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Ap1a2</a></li>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Ap1a3</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c3" class="menu_label">Menu Am1b1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c3" />
        <ol>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Ap1b1</a></li>

          <li>
            <label for="c4" class="menu_label">Menu Am2b1 </label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c4" />
            <ol>
              <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Ap2b1</a></li>
            </ol></li>
        </ol></li>
    </ol></li>

  <li>
    <label class="menu_label" for="c5">Menu Bm0a1</label>
    <input type="checkbox" id="c5" />
    <ol>
      <li>
        <label for="c6" class="menu_label">Menu Bm1a1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c6" />
        <ol>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Bp1a1</a></li>
        </ol>
      </li>
      <li>
        <label for="c7" class="menu_label">Menu Bm1b1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c7" />
        <ol>
          <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Bp1b1</a></li>
          <li>
            <label for="c8" class="menu_label">Menu Bm2b1</label>
            <input type="checkbox" id="c8" />
            <ol>
              <li class="page"><a href="#">Page Bp2b1</a></li>
            </ol></li>
        </ol></li>
    </ol></li>

</ol>
```

and my css is

```
#menutree li {
   list-style: none;          /* all list item li dots invisible */
         }

   li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox] {
      opacity: 2;             /* checkboxes invisible and use no space */
     }                        /* display: none; is better but fails in ie8 */

    li .menu_label {
      cursor: pointer;        /* cursor changes when you mouse over this class */
    }                         /* could add the many user-select: none; commands here */

      li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox] + ol > li
         {
            display: none;         /* prevents sublists below unchecked labels from displaying */
         }

      li .menu_label + input[type=checkbox]:checked + ol > li
         {
           display: block;         /* display submenu on click */
         }
```

Now the issue is check boxes are displayed after the label and i need the check boxes before the label.

So can anyone help me solving this??

Note:After displaying the check box before label the functionality should work as previously.....

thanks.

here i am attaching the jsfiddle link
[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/6LKc6/301/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This technique works by using the adjacent sibling combinator `+`, so for

```
input[type=checkbox] + foo
```

to work, the element `foo` must be following the `input` element immediately. If you reverse the order of the `input` and the `label` in your HTML, then that condition isn’t satisfied any more.

But you can rectify that by changing those selector parts to

```
input[type=checkbox] + label + foo
```

so that you can have an HTML structure like

```
<input>
<label>
<foo>
```

instead, and have the checked input still influence the styling of that `foo` element or its descendants.
Instead of applying to `foo` elements that directly follow an `input`, it now applies to `foo` that directly follow a `label` that directly follows an `input` – same principle, just with “one step” inserted in between.

I modified your fiddle here to show that in action: http://jsfiddle.net/6LKc6/302/

*(Your original fiddle included a full HTML document in the HTML panel, although that is not necessary resp. rather counter-productive. Next time please adhere to the warning that jsfiddle shows you when inserting a full HTML document there, and only input the body contents.)*

Your original fiddle contained a comment after the input fields,

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c1" /> <!-- input must follow label for safari -->
```

– I don’t know what that was meant for, and I have no easy way of testing in Safari right now, so please do that yourself to ensure the modified version still works as expected.
(I know that certain older versions of some browsers have problems in general with using pseudo classes and the adjacent sibling combinator together like this – but if that was relevant here, then the original version should most likely not have worked in those in the first place.)

Comment: thanks for giving the brief explanation and sure i will learn the way of posting the questions as soon as possible and special thanks for suggestion

Answer (score 0):

you are writing like that

```
 <label for="c2" class="menu_label">Menu Am1a1</label>
        <input type="checkbox" id="c2" />
```

change to

```
<input type="checkbox" id="c2" />
<label for="c2" class="menu_label">Menu Am1a1</label>
```

Comment: ,thanks for responding but i have tried with that i couldnt solve the issue can u send me the working of it if it works for you.

Comment: do you want li checkbox displayed after the label or ol lable ?

Comment: check box is displaying before label but functionality is not working like when i click on check box it is not closing the sub menus can u see in to that as well

Comment: check if you want like this :) im not good in css so i have done with jquery okkay  :)  http://jsfiddle.net/876ke4re/

Comment: Thanks Tariq but it is not working for sub menus can u look in to that issue?????

Comment: okkay i have only done for main menu. wait i will do for submenu too